# Zooming out to fit the size of a canvas entirely (on iPhone, Android, etc)

Tags: android, iphone, html, html5-canvas

I am making an HTML5 canvas performance benchmark for different screen sizes. To bring maximal objectivity in scoring, the canvas on which the benchmark will be with a fixed size - i.e. it will not shrink or fit to match the screen size. I believe that this should remain so, because testing on a small screen with a small canvas is an unfair comparison against a large one.

Nevertheless, I saw that on screens, smaller than the size of the canvas, the canvas is not rendered fully, and I believe this will affect the end score. Also, I do not want the users to tap twice to fit the canvas, because handling the user event will also affect the score.

How can I make sure that screens smaller then the size of the canvas ALWAYS zoom out to fit the canvas entirely? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing the screen size with a meta query, and disable zooming. Swap 320 to whatever your canvas width is.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Still, I don't know how this will react to screens smaller than the desired width.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/DCNVZ/) that might help you with resize problems.

The main point of the code is that you set the canvas width and height (your canvas resolution!) once, and using css the area where your canvas is placed resizes automatically to fit the screen in the way you configure.

Here is the code. But don't forget to see it [***in action***](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/DCNVZ/).

HTML:

```
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="gameArea">
      <canvas id="gameCanvas" />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#gameArea {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
#gameCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function (limit_canvas_size, stretch_to_fit) {

var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
var game_area = document.getElementById('gameArea');

// try with different resolutions !
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

var aspect_ratio = canvas.width / canvas.height;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
    context.save();
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    context.restore();
}

function resize() {
    // start with canvas original aspect ratio
    var widthToHeight = aspect_ratio;
    var newWidthToHeight = aspect_ratio;

    // cache the window dimensions
    var newWidth = window.innerWidth,
        newHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (limit_canvas_size) {
        // fit smaller screen entirely but maintain the resolution on bigger screens
        newWidth = newWidth <= canvas.width ? newWidth : canvas.width;
        newHeight = newHeight <= canvas.height ? newHeight : canvas.height;
        // this will be the visual aspect ratio
        newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;
    }

    if (stretch_to_fit) {
        // overwrite the current canvas aspect ratio to fit the entire screen
        widthToHeight = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    }

    // special case (only fit the screen if window is smaller than resolution)
    if (stretch_to_fit && limit_canvas_size) {
        newWidth = canvas.width;
        newHeight = canvas.height;
        newWidth = window.innerWidth <= newWidth ? window.innerWidth : newWidth;
        newHeight = window.innerHeight <= newHeight ? window.innerHeight : newHeight;
        // this will be the visual aspect ratio
        widthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;
    }
    else {        
        // this will be the visual aspect ratio 
        newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;
    }

    // scale the game area using CSS        
    if (newWidthToHeight > widthToHeight) {
        newWidth = newHeight * widthToHeight;
        game_area.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        game_area.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
    } else {
        newHeight = newWidth / widthToHeight;
        game_area.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
        game_area.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    }

    // adjust the game area position
    game_area.style.marginTop = (-newHeight / 2) + 'px';
    game_area.style.marginLeft = (-newWidth / 2) + 'px';

};

// listen to resize events
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    resize();        
}, false);

// also resize the screen on orientation changes
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
    resize();        
}, false);

// draw something in the canvas
// note that you dont need to redraw on resize since the canvas element stays intact    
draw();

// first resize
resize();

})(false, false); // setup 3
```

You can setup the above code as shown next:

1. Resize canvas to fit the entire screen in all screen sizes:
   Change the anonymous function parameters to (false, true). This will make 
    `limit_canvas_size = false, stretch_to_fit = true`
2. Resize canvas to fit the screen but maintain the canvas aspect ratio in all screen sizes:
   Change the anonymous function parameters to (false, false). This will make 
    `limit_canvas_size = false, stretch_to_fit = false`
3. Resize canvas to fit the screen in small screen sizes only but maintain the aspect ratio:
   Change the anonymous function parameters to (true, false). This will make 
    `limit_canvas_size = true, stretch_to_fit = false`
4. Resize canvas to fit the entire screen in small screens only:
   Change the anonymous function parameters to (true, true). This will make 
    `limit_canvas_size = true, stretch_to_fit = true`

So to your specific case you should use setup 3 or 4;